# Creating multiple LI tags with different link in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

How can I create multiple `li` elements having the same style, in `cakephp`? This is the code that I am trying obtain with `cakephp`.

```
<ul class="z-nav__list-secondary">
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog.html">Blog with sidebar</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog-full.html">Blog fullwidth</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog-masonry.html">Blog masonry</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog-timeline.html">Blog timeline</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="single-post.html">Single post with sidebar</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="single-post-full.html">Single post fullwidth</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog-audio.html">Blog audio</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog-video.html">Blog video</a></li>
    <li class="z-nav__item"><a class="z-nav__link" href="blog-author.html">Post author</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Doesn't your view just have a loop (e.g., `foreach` ) with an `echo` for every <li>?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP, it's just php (at least that you get the css clases from some element from the controller or something)

Comment: You should use a foreach (as suggested by @AgRizzo) in your view, and use the [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links) to generate the links html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the codes below:

- Html->link('Blog with sidebar',array('controller' 
   =>'pages','action' => 'blog'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Blog fullwidth',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'blog-full'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Blog masonry',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'blog-masonry'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Blog timeline',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'blog-timeline'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Single post with sidebar',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'single-post'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Single post fullwidth',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'single-post-full'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Blog audio',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'blog-audio'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Blog video',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'blog-video'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Html->link('Post author',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'blog-author'),array('class'=>'z-nav__link')); ?>

Edit your routes.php

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display','blog'));
```

In Pages directory create the all the files with. ctp extension
Im using cakephp2.6